# tomcat jms jndi naming exception

Tags: tomcat, jms, tomcat7, activemq-classic, jndi

Hi i am trying to implement jms connector using jndi in tomcat server. but i am getting

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
```

I am not writing resouces in server.xml file, instead of that i am writing the resource in context.xml file of my spring project. I have tested the following configuration with DataSource and its working fine, but while testing it with JMS i am facing naming exception

following is my jndi configuration.

context.xml

```
<Context crossContext="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource name="jms/ConnectionFactory" auth="Container"
                 type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
                 description="JMS Connection Factory"
                 factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
                 brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
                 brokerName="LocalActiveMQBroker"
                 userName="admin" password="admin"
                 useEmbeddedBroker="false"
                 clientID="TomcatClientID" />

    <Resource name="jms/myQueue" auth="Container"
                 type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue"
                 description="JMS Queue"
                 factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
                 physicalName="app.jms.queue" />
</Context>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jms/ConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jms/myQueue</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.Queue</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

my java class:-

```
Context envContext = new InitialContext();
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory");
```

I have added the following jar in my tomcate_home/lib directory

apache-activemq-4.1.0-incubator.jar

or

activemq-all_5.4.jar
commons-loggin.jar

i am using tomcat 8 standalone server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had loads of trouble with this before (all sorts of classloader issues, class cast exceptions etc). I'm not sure exactly what the most correct solution is, but what worked for me was:

Made sure there were no activemq or jms related jars in my project's web-inf/lib. In Tomcat's lib folder, activemq-client-5.8.0.jar, geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar, geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.jar (ensure no other jms or activemq-related jars are present).

project's web.xml:

```
<resource-env-ref>
  <description>
    ActiveMQ Topic Connection factory
  </description>
  <resource-env-ref-name>
    jms/flex/TopicConnectionFactory
  </resource-env-ref-name>
  <resource-env-ref-type>
    org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
  </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>     

<resource-env-ref>
  <description>
    ActiveMQ Topic to which a bootstrap request for a users orders are sent
  </description>
  <resource-env-ref-name>
    jms/topic
  </resource-env-ref-name>
  <resource-env-ref-type>
    org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic
  </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Tomcat's web.xml:

```
<resource-ref> 
    <res-ref-name>jms/flex/TopicConnectionFactory</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Tomcat's server.xml:

```
<Resource name="jms/flex/TopicConnectionFactory" 
          auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
          factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
          brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
          />
```

Tomcat's context.xml:

```
<ResourceLink global="jms/flex/TopicConnectionFactory" name="jms/flex/TopicConnectionFactory" type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"/>
```

I must stress again that this is only what worked for me, and no doubt more experienced developers are reading this and cringing, but I hope it helps!

Comment: hi Matt, which version of tomcat and active mq are you using ??

Comment: I'm using activemq 5.8.0 and Tomcat 6.0.24, so syntax may be slightly different for you...